# focus input, selected by id of parent

Tags: jquery

I would like to focus the `<input>` element.

```
<div id="table_filter" class="dataTables_filter">
    <label>Suche:
        <input type="search" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Suchbegriff(e)" >
    </label>
</div>
```

I tried:

```
$("#table_filter").children().children()[0].focus;
```

Comment: `focus` is a method.  use `$("#table_filter").children().children()[0].focus();` or better still `$("#table_filter input").focus()`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`focus`](https://api.jquery.com/focus/) in `jQuery` is a method. You have to select the target using your selector and call `focus` using `focus()`.

You can also use these selectors to select your target

```
$("#table_filter input[type='search']")
```

OR

```
$("#table_filter input.form-control.form-control-sm")
```

**Working Fiddle**

```js
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#table_filter").children().children()[0].focus();
        // $("#table_filter input[type='search']").focus();
        // $("#table_filter input.form-control.form-control-sm").focus();
    });
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="table_filter" class="dataTables_filter">
    <label>Suche:
        <input type="search" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Suchbegriff(e)">
    </label>
</div>
```